# sql query issue for group_concat

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

the below  query working fine

```
 SELECT listing_offer . * , (

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( c1.card_name )
FROM merchant_card AS c1
WHERE FIND_IN_SET( c1.id, listing_offer.cc_ids )
) AS cardname, (

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( c2.outlet_name )
FROM merchant_employer AS c2
WHERE FIND_IN_SET( c2.id, listing_offer.outlet_id )
) AS outletname
FROM `listing_offer`
ORDER BY listing_offer.id
```

and the same i am trying to implement on my company's mvc structure 
but seems not to be working.

```
$obj_model_coupon = $this->app->load_model("listing_offer");
        $rs = $obj_model_coupon->execute("SELECT", true, "

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( c1.card_name )
FROM merchant_card AS c1
WHERE FIND_IN_SET( c1.id, listing_offer.cc_ids )
 AS cardname, (

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( c2.outlet_name )
FROM merchant_employer AS c2
WHERE FIND_IN_SET( c2.id, listing_offer.outlet_id )
) AS outletname
ORDER BY listing_offer.id","", "");
```

Comment: not sure how ur mvc code works but the query looks like missing `FROM listing_offer`

Comment: in execute there is select defined so its automatically including thats why i cannot copy paste complete sql i need to divide it as so not working :(

Comment: yes seems like it will not, the mvc should have something for select list, then where condition , group by etc

Comment: correct hey pls see this if you could make this two lines correct its direct sql then it would work :)
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( c1.card_name)  FROM merchant_card as c1 WHERE  FIND_IN_SET(c1.id, listing_offer.cc_ids)) AS cardname,
         (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( c2.outlet_name)  FROM merchant_employer as c2 WHERE  FIND_IN_SET(c2.id, listing_offer.outlet_id)) AS outletname

Comment: You have this tagged as MySQL and SQL Server.  Which database are you using?  If SQL Server, the problem is obvious, because you are using MySQL-specific functionality.

Comment: i think i have tagged the same bro

Comment: @user3177068: *Using MySQL syntax on SQL Server raises error* is what GordonLinoff is saying

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: @Ravinder could you help to rectify the query ?
i am using mysql server only 
thanks
MySQL client version: mysqlnd 5.0.7-dev - 091210 - $Revision: 294543 $
Used PHP extensions: mysqli

Comment: You tagged `sql-server-2008` are you trying to run `GROUP_CONCAT()` on sql server ? Seems not, remove the tag ;)

Comment: @user3177068: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AS cardname, (

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( c2.outlet_name )
FROM merchant_employer A' at line 4

Comment: @Ravinder why you removed your answer?

Comment: @user3177068: Can you post a link to `execute` documentation online?

Comment: could you tell me how to do that for reference i will do it 
thanks